# Filtering of nested lists with Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, nested-lists, predicate

I have a to filter on some nested Lists. Consider a `List<A>` which contains `List<B>` which contains `List<C>`. I need to filter, to return all the A Objects which contain at least one B which satisfies a given condition, and at least one C which satisfies a given condition.

I've got a contrived example below, which basically is doing what I've tried to implement in my actual example. Take a list of schools in a city Each school has many subjects, and each subject has many teachers. I want to retain a list of schools which has subject.subjectName = 'Math' and at least one teacher within this subject where teacher.age > 65.

I have implemented this using a custom predicate, so I've also made a this in my example.
I'm getting an error where 'cannot convert from boolean to Stream' but honestly, I'm struggling in this scenario.

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class School {
        private String schoolId;
        private List<Subject> classes;
        
    }
        
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Subject {
        String subjectName;
        List<Teacher> teachers;
    }
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    class Teacher {
        private String teacherName;
        private Integer age;
    }

    public class TestClass {
        public static void main( String[] args ){
            List<School> schools;
            
            // Get All schools where A mathTeacher is over retirement age
            List<School> schoolsWithRetirementAgeMathTeachers = schools.stream()
                    .filter(school -> null != school.getClasses())
                    .flatMap(school -> {
                        return school.getClasses().stream()
                                .filter(subject -> subject.getSubjectName().equalsIgnoreCase("Math"))
                                .filter(subject -> null != subject.getTeachers())
                                .flatMap(subject -> {
                                    return subject.getTeachers().stream()
                                            .filter(teacher -> teacher != null)
                                            .anyMatch(isRetirementAge);
                                });
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    
        }
                
        public static Predicate<Teacher> isRetirementAge = teacher -> teacher.getAge() > 65;
    
    }
```

Comment: Is this `C` you're filtering for under the `B` you're filtering for or are they unrelated conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for `School`s as an output, you do not need to `map`/`flatmap` your stream into another object. The `filter`ing capability has to be smart enough to go through the nested collections and confirm if there was `anyMatch` based on your requirements.

Primarily in the below code, we filter all those schools where a subject by the name "Math" is present and one of the teachers teaching Maths is above the mentioned retirement age.

```
// Get All schools where a Math teacher is over retirement age
List<School> schoolsWithRetirementAgeMathTeachers = schools.stream()
        .filter(school -> school.getSubjects()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(subject ->
                        subject.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Math") &&
                                subject.getTeachers()
                                        .stream()
                                        .anyMatch(isRetirementAge)
                ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: And if I wanted to extend this, to retain only the instances in the 'Subjects' list where the name = math, i.e. I want to filter out these.. as currently it's only returning the schools with a match, but all the subjects underneath are still present

Comment: to get the subjects of a school, then you would have to `map` your stream

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to return the parent objects, you don't want to use `flatMap()`. You just need to nest some `anyMatch()` calls:

```
List<A> filtered = listA.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getListB()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(b -> testB(b) && b.getListC()
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(c -> testC(c))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: And if I wanted to extend this, instead of only seeking to check the presence of a nested value, I wanted to filter out all values which didnt satisfy the condition? I.e. each `A` would have a  `List<B>` only having items which met the condition `testB()`. Likewise, each `B` would have a `List<C>` which contained only those `C` items which met the condition of `testC()` .. how would I do this? it's essentially combining nested filtering and retaining the filter outside the scope of the stream

Comment: Then you would need a `map()` to create a filtered copy of each element. Unless you're willing to modify the lists in place.

Comment: if i am looking to get a filtered copy of each element, but I also do not want to modify the originals, would that mean i would have to create copies of A that have filtered copies of b and filtered copies of c?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X This only filters out top-level elements (based on the nested contents). If you want to create filtered copies at multiple levels, maybe add a method to `A` like `A filtered(Predicate<B> p1, Predicate<C> p2) { return new A(bList.stream().filter(p1).map(b -> b.filtered(p2)).toList()); }`.